# I am not able to cut excess white spaces between two divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that although I used `padding-bottom:0;` in style for the class `.title` but there are still white spaces between `.title` and `#about_restaurant`. May I ask if I want to cut the excess white spaces between two elements what is the best way to solve it?

```css
#about_restaurant {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.delivery_image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.delivery_image img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.describe_restaurant {
  float: left;
}

.describe_restaurant h2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="About">
    <h2 class="title">About Restaurant</h2>
    <div id="about_restaurant">
      <div class="delivery_image">
        <img src="delivery.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      </div>
      <div class="describe_restaurant">
        <h2>Our restaurant aimed to provide delivery service to the customers. We hope the service and the quality of food could satisfy the customers' expectations. Welcome to support our delivery service.
        </h2>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try margin-bottom:0 ? also you can try to about restaurant margin-top:0 and padding-top:0 if they are static

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: `.delivery-image` also has 1em of padding on all sides so that is contributing too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That white space is the default margin of the header (`<h2></h2>`). you can reset it by using: `h2 { margin: 0; }` in your css file.

`Paddings` are the inside spacing of an element. However the white-space is not added in the inside of an element but outside. The outside spacing is called `margin`. As such, `padding: 0;` wont help you here.

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#about_restaurant {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.delivery_image {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.delivery_image img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.describe_restaurant {
  float: left;
}

.describe_restaurant h2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="About">
    <h2 class="title">About Restaurant</h2>
    <div id="about_restaurant">
      <div class="delivery_image">
        <img src="delivery.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      </div>
      <div class="describe_restaurant">
        <h2>Our restaurant aimed to provide delivery service to the customers. We hope the service and the quality of food could satisfy the customers' expectations. Welcome to support our delivery service.
        </h2>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .title{
       text-align:center;
       background-color:aqua;
       padding-bottom:0;
       margin-bottom:0;
    }
```

or :

```
<h2 class="title" style="margin-bottom:0;">About Restaurant</h2>
```